# vlc plugin in firefox fail to decode hardware acceleration

Tags: javascript, firefox

I installed vlc media player v2.2.0 with firefox v44.0( browser-plugin-vlc 2.2.4.2) in ubuntu MATE v15.04 VIVID (ARMHF platform).

Firefox loads the html file whose content is like this:

```
  <embed autostart="true" type="application/x-vlc-plugin"  pluginspage="http://www.videolan.org" width="100%" height="100%" id="vlc" target="/home/fa/Downloads/media.mpg">
```

When the firefox is running with vlc plugin, the video play is very slow, the CPU load is about 100%.

In the log, it seems no hw decoder modules matched and the sw decoder is working instead which oppucied too much CPU load.

The Firefox_VLC_plugin_log is as below:

```
[b01b5c70] avcodec decoder debug: available hardware decoder output format 53 (vaapi_vld)
[b07b9ba0] core input debug: Buffering 14%
[b01b5c70] avcodec decoder debug: available hardware decoder output format 109 (vdpau)
[b01b5c70] avcodec decoder debug: available software decoder output format 0 (yuv420p)
[b07b9ba0] core input debug: Buffering 15%
[b016e650] core generic debug: looking for hw decoder module matching "any": 4 candidates
[b016e650] vdpau_avcodec generic error: Xlib is required for VDPAU
[b016e650] core generic debug: no hw decoder modules matched
```

I tried setting vlc preference, of which "input & codecs" settings , tick Use GPU acceleration but it still doesn't work.

However, I tried in command line in the same system. The code is 
vlc media.mpg, It runs well.
the log is as following:

```
[VDPAU SUNXI] VE version 0x1680 opened
[VDPAU SUNXI] OSD disabled!
[a5c42c18] avcodec decoder: Using sunxi VDPAU Driver for hardware decoding.
```

Can anyone help me how to force to open the hardware decompression in the vlc plugin firefox in ubutun, armhf platform?

Comment: Isn't the VLC browser plugin basically abandoned?

Answer (score 0):

I hope not, that's my only means of playing UDP streams in a browser :(

Comment: Sorry that was meant to be a reply to Alexander